# cakePHP session not storing password

Tags: session, cakephp, authentication, passwords

My concern is that after I login using the Auth->login() method, all the data regarding the User is stored in session but NOT the password. I wonder is it normal? and how can I specifically choose what fields I want to store in session when logging in.

Comment: storing passwords in sessions is not safe at all, and there should be no reason to do it.

Comment: Ok thanks for answering, that's what i thought even though it's hashed with SALT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restating what I said in comments: *storing passwords in sessions is not safe at all, and there should be no reason to do it*.

Really, don't do it. ***Don't***.

Let's enter in fantasy world. If the Auth component saves the password in session, it has two possibilities to do so: save it as plaintext, or save it hashed and salted.

Scenario one:
It would be the same as writing your password in your forehead, take a selfie, and post it on facebook (or the next new social network). Anyone that sees your session (it can be done) will have your plaintext password. And if the user uses the same password for everything... yay free amazon shopping!!

Scenario two:
it is "safer" in a way that is not plaintext. But the safest thing? Not giving anyone the least bit of info about the password. Is easier to decrypt something if you know the final product. Meaning by brute force, if I know a plain password "12345" is hashed and salted and produces "i8g04", and I have the same thing for a lot of other users, eventually I'll be able to deduce what salt you used and how to hash it. "Eventually" maybe meaning instead of 2^58 is 2^57 tries by brute force. That's a lot less time and processing (1.4411519e+17 according to google). So... nah, better not to do it. And for what would you (or cake) use that hashed-salted password for?

> and how can I specifically choose what fields I want to store in session when logging in

I don't know a way to do it, there's just one optional parameter in `login`, so no options there... you could extend the Auth component to add the functionality if you want... But if you want to do this for something specific, maybe you'd be better off explaining your reasons to us and we could give you advice on how to do it.

PD: I repeat, *don't store passwords in session*.

Comment: Well I totally understand your point even though your story is very VERY unlikely, so I have to query the DB again if I want to update the password